# doubt about xacro

Tags: ros, param-server, xacro, parameter, parameter-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I have a doubt about XACRO.
Is possible from xacro to read a  parameters in the Parameters Servers?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36812/doubt-about-xacro/) by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-19**:
In case your use case is to use a ros parameter when using xacro to initialize another ros parameter inside roslaunch: that won't work because parameters are first all parsed and then set on the parameter server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think this is possible, but it is an interesting possibility. What is your use case?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1